# Internet Explorer7 sending 2 requests but Firefox and other only one?

Tags: debugging, firefox, internet-explorer-7, firebug

I'm using Internet Explorer 7 and Firefox/15.0.1. I developed a web application in J2EE.
In application,if i click any hyperlink it is sending only one request in Firefox,chrome.
I checked it using Firebug and the logs also.
The same way i tested in IE7,It is showing 2 times logs for a single request.
Is it a bug in IE7? How to fix it?
Every time IE7 sending two requests.. Any tool to track the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly the problem with two forms i'm using...
that is a form with in other form. which caused IE to show exotic behaviour.
HTML is not well formatted. I changed it. it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can install IE Developer Toolbar to debug JavaScript in IE